# Updating object in vueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm creating an upload VueJS component and I've this portion to display the images in the `images` object:

```
    <div class="row">
        <figure class="col-md-3" v-for="image in images">
            <img :src="'/'+image.image" :alt="image.description+'-'+image.image" class="img-responsive"
                 style="width:100%;">
        </figure>
    </div>
```

I want to know if there's a way yo image the `images` after every successful upload and to get the newly uploaded images.

Here's the the method I'm using to submit the images :

```
props: ['data'],
    data() {
        return {
            files: [],
            slug: this.data.slug,
            id: this.data.part.id,
            images : this.data.part.images
        }
    },
    methods: {

        submitFiles() {
            let formData = new FormData();
            for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
                let file = this.files[i];

                formData.append('files[' + i + ']', file);
            }

            axios.post('/dashboard/galleries/',
                formData,
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
                    }
                }
            ).then(function () {
                console.log('SUCCESS!!');
            })
                .catch(function () {
                    console.log('FAILURE!!');
                });
        }
```

Thanks to everyone for helping.

Comment: So your question is how to display the images after uploading successfully?

Comment: @AmrAly yes that's it. I want to refresh the `images` object after the upload is successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do is after uploading your files is to return a response containing your images urls like so:

```
return response()->json(['images' => $images]);
```

and then in your `.then` block you can assign the response to your `images` piece of data like so:

```
axios.post('/dashboard/galleries/',
    formData,
    {
      headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }
    ).then(function (res) {
        this.images = res.data.images;
    })
```

### update

since the data is going to change when we get the response we will need to use [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property) like so:

```
props: ...,
methods: ...,
watch: {
  images: function(val) {
    this.images = val;
  }
}
```

Comment: so you have received the response with images?

Comment: Yes I received the response with the images but the data property won't update

Comment: @AmrAlu I've updated the question because I've forgotten to mention that at first I'm getting the images from the a property

Answer (score 0):

use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL to display image from base64 string. There is a simple example.